# Allow Django to have a different database for each user?

Tags: database, django

I would like to create a Django app where each user has their own database. Users would still get authenticated from a master User, but all app models would come from their own copy of a database.

For example, let's say that we have something like:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'NAME': 'sqlite3',
    'ENGINE': 'default.db',
},
'user1': {
    'NAME': 'sqlite3',
    'ENGINE': 'user1.db',
}
'user2': {
    'NAME': 'sqlite3',
    'ENGINE': 'user2.db',
}
```

}

where default.db has the User (and any other non-app tables), and user1.db and user2.db have the app-specific models.

How could I allow some users to use user1 and others to use user2?

Can I add more entries to DATABASES on the fly? (I'm using wsgi if that matters)

I'd prefer not to change code (say, by inserting .using()) but rather have a global Database Router, perhaps.

I've read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/ but can't figure out what is necessary to do the above.

Comment: Not possible with stock Django. It only supports granularity up the the model level, i.e. you can tell it to route all requests for `auth.User` to one DB and everything else to another DB. It doesn't support conditional routing based on runtime values (current user, for example). There *may* be a 3rd-party app that will let you do this, but in general, it sounds like a hugely bad idea. What's your actual use-case? Or, why do you think you need to do this. I'm pretty sure there's probably a better way.

Comment: The app is a genealogy family tree manager (http://gramps-connect.org/ is a demo). I'd like to be able to host users where each has their own copy of the tables. BTW, the database can also be used in the desktop application as well (Gramps).

Comment: Just use the same tables for everyone and key them by the user they belong to. When giving them a copy for the desktop app, you'd simply write their data to some sort of export format (XML, JSON, etc) and have the desktop app import it. Having a separate database per user is unfeasible. Consider for example if you need to make a schema change. Propagating that change across all the databases for each user without accidentally borking something will be a nightmare.

Comment: I agree with Chris--not to mention the overhead of maintaing so many simultaneous database connections could prove quite burdensome.

Comment: Re-reading, I see that you're using SQLite, which may negate my connection concerns.  But Chris' concerns are still quite valid.

Comment: I hadn't considered the database connections. But would that really be a memory burden? I could, of course, add a special key field to every table. Would there be a way that I could abstract a Database Manager to make sure that every app query contained the additional constraint [eg, Q(keyfield=user)]? That would be preferable to touching every database access point in the code. Migrating schemas is already hard, BTW. I usually export/import anyway, which could be automated across all databases.

Comment: It *looks* like I can subclass a Manager https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/ adding the additional constraint to the get_query_set method, and this will have the effect I want. I'll need to probably adjust the indexes, but no other code need change. Thanks for talking me out of my original suspect idea!

Comment: Say that I have a filter set in the get_query_set of my new Manager, how do I tie the query to a particular user? For example, let's say that user1 is logged in, with a session, and I want to limit the database to only see user1's data? I don't have access to a "request" object inside the Manager.

Comment: D.S.  How did you end up resolving this problem?

Comment: AgDude: I haven't resolved the issue yet. On the one hand, doing what is suggested in the comments here (ie, don't have many files, use just one, each with a userID) makes sense, if I can work around the techinal challenges (like having the userID available as some kind of global). However, as I am integrating with an external application I may still try to try to trick Django into letting me switch the DB dynamically.

Comment: I've done some stuff with multi-tenancy and Postgres schemata (per customer) at [django-boardinghouse](https://django-boardinghouse.readthedocs.org), but it's not currently in production use. It does show one mechanism for changing database settings on the fly (per-request). It's all one database, though, so can share connections easily.